# Intermediate Value Theorem (continuity)

Tags: continuity

By using the Intermediate value theorem.

Show that f is continuos on $[-1,1]$, then there exist n in the natural numbers such that the equation $f(x) + n = n(e^x)$ has a solution in $[-1,1]$.

I'm having trouble solving this problem.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), and show your work, where are you having trouble, where are stuck...

Answer (score 1):

Define $g(x) := f(x) + n - n(e^x)$. Then $g$ is continuous and we have $g(-1) = f(-1) + n - \frac{n}{e}$ and $g(1) = f(1) + n - ne$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you Shuster